# What is the best way to define bool variables in Firebase Remote Config

Tags: firebase, performance, firebase-remote-config

In firebase remote config you can define a bool variable in two ways:

- As a `bool`: true/false
- As a `String`: "true"/"false"

[image: example]

and then if you read them from the code it parse it into the expected value, an example from flutter code:

[image: flutter example]

The question is that if it is less optimal using a string or is the same thing? what are the consequences of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While using a boolean provides some increased efficiency over using a string, it's likely to be marginal in this context as:

- These values are not fetched frequently.
- They come over the network, which will outweigh any performance impact of parsing the values.

My main reasons for picking a certain type is:

- It documents the expectation of the values. If a type is a string, it could have any all kinds of values. If it's a boolean, it can be only true or false.
- The console and API for setting values can validate values you set. If you have the value as a string, you could enter "Hello world" as the value. That might be exactly what you want, but if not... the console/API can't detect the mistake for you. Marking the param as a boolean ensures that it can only be true or false, and nothing else.